# Adding a context variable to an existing context

Tags: python

How can I add a context variable to an existing context?

For example:

```
context = {'name': 'Andrew', 'age': 43}
```

I now want to add:

```
{'city': 'London'}
```

How can I do this without declaring the context all in one go?

Comment: This is just a standard dict. Either direct assignment or `update()` would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In dictionary you can use **update** to append the data.You can use following code to do so:

```
   context = {'name': 'Andrew', 'age': 43}
   context.update({'city': 'London'})
   print context
```

output:

```
 {'city': 'London', 'age': 43, 'name': 'Andrew'}
```

Answer (score 5):

Is there something wrong with direct dict-style assignment? I don't have a Django install handy to confirm, but the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#playing-with-context-objects) and my memory say it should work. Assuming it does, it's more idiomatic than using `update` for a single key.

```
context = {'name': 'Andrew', 'age': 43}
context['city'] = 'london'
```

Actually, that's not even a context object yet (as Daniel Roseman points out in a comment above), it's just a normal dict. Direct assignment also works after you've created the context object, as shown in the linked docs. Assuming your Django tag on the question and the reference to contexts means you're working with Django contexts at some point.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `.update` method:

```
>>> context = {'name': 'Andrew', 'age': 43}
>>> context.update({'city': 'London'})
>>> context
{'age': 43, 'city': 'London', 'name': 'Andrew'}
```